# Create new post into wordpress when new product is published

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'd like to create automatic post into Wordpress when I create a new product into Woocommerce.

I'd like to use the title of the product and the link of this product.

So the function read the "title for this product" that become the title for the article (post)
The "link for this product" become the "content" of the post (that create a snapshot into the post)

But this post must be published only if product is published and "active". If a product is not published, so the post is not published.

And the better way is that all modification for a product don"t create a new post but update the post in relation...

Can somebody can help me with this? Thanks in advance

Is there any way ? not in the good way ?

Comment: Hi Jérôme and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, we can't give you step-by-step instructions to accomplish this task. Stack Overflow isn't an on-demand coding service. Instead, tell us what have you tried so far (in terms of programming) and we'll do our best to help you out. Also, please take some time to take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what kind of questions are acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function add_this_to_new_products that run when new product is created and complete with wp_insert_post for create new post (complete with your data).

```
function add_this_to_new_products( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

global $post;

if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) return;

if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ) return;

 $post = array( 
    'ID'             => [ <post id> ] 
    'post_content'   => [ <string> ] 
    'post_name'      => [ <string> ] 
    'post_title'     => [ <string> ] 
    'post_status'    => [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ] 
    'post_type'      => [ 'post' | 'page' | 'link' | 'nav_menu_item' | custom post type ] 
    'post_author'    => [ <user ID> ] // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
    'ping_status'    => [ 'closed' | 'open' ] // Pingbacks or trackbacks allowed. Default is the option 'default_ping_status'.
    'post_parent'    => [ <post ID> ] // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.
    'menu_order'     => [ <order> ] // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
    'to_ping'        => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs to ping. Default empty string.
    'pinged'         => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs that have been pinged. Default empty string.
    'post_password'  => [ <string> ] // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
    'guid'           => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
    'post_content_filtered' => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
    'post_excerpt'   => [ <string> ] // For all your post excerpt needs.
    'post_date'      => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made.
    'post_date_gmt'  => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made, in GMT.
    'comment_status' => [ 'closed' | 'open' ] // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
    'post_category'  => [ array(<category id>, ...) ] // Default empty.
    'tags_input'     => [ '<tag>, <tag>, ...' | array ] // Default empty.
    'tax_input'      => [ array( <taxonomy> => <array | string> ) ] // For custom taxonomies. Default empty.
    'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg template.php. Default empty.
    );  

    wp_insert_post($new_post);

} 
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'add_this_to_new_products', 10, 3 );
```

Let me know.

Comment: Ok, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`````
global $post;

if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) return;
// On récupère les données dont on a besoin pour créer le nouveau post  
// Get $product object from product ID

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Now you have access to (see above)...

//$product->get_type();
$product->get_name();
$nomduproduit = $product->get_name();
// On récupère l'URL du Jeu
$jeuurl = get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ) ;


if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ) return;

$post = array( 
   //'ID'             => [ <post id> ] 
   'post_content'   => return '<a href="'. $jeuurl .'">'. $item_name .'</a>';  
   'post_name'      => [ '$nomduproduit' ] 
   'post_title'     => [ '$nomduproduit' ] 
   'post_status'    => [ 'publish' ] 
   'post_type'      => [ 'post' ] 
   'post_author'    => [ 'BingoHome' ] // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
   'ping_status'    => [ 'open' ] // Pingbacks or trackbacks allowed. Default is the option 'default_ping_status'.
   'post_parent'    => [ '$product_id' ] // Sets the parent of the new post, if any. Default 0.
   //'menu_order'     => [ <order> ] // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
   //'to_ping'        => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs to ping. Default empty string.
   //'pinged'         => // Space or carriage return-separated list of URLs that have been pinged. Default empty string.
   //'post_password'  => [ <string> ] // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
   //'guid'           => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
   //'post_content_filtered' => // Skip this and let Wordpress handle it, usually.
   'post_excerpt'   => [ <string> ] // For all your post excerpt needs.
   'post_date'      => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made.
   'post_date_gmt'  => [ Y-m-d H:i:s ] // The time post was made, in GMT.
   'comment_status' => [ 'closed' | 'open' ] // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
   'post_category'  => [ array(<category id>, ...) ] // Default empty.
   'tags_input'     => [ '' | array ] // Default empty.
   'tax_input'      => [ array( <taxonomy> => <array | string> ) ] // For custom taxonomies. Default empty.
   'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg template.php. Default empty.
   );  

   wp_insert_post($new_post);

} ````   

What do you think ?
`````